# RotationGesture not call when PinchGesture active

Tags: ios

I have drawingView and listen UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer, and UIPinchGestureRecognizer on it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [self.drawingView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateRecognizer:)];
    [self.drawingView addGestureRecognizer:rotateRecognizer];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchRecognizer:)];
    [self.drawingView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    [self.drawingView reloadData];
}

-(void) pinchRecognizer:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
    return;
    NSLog(@"Call scale");
}

- (void)rotateRecognizer:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Call rotaion");
}
```

If i only choose UIRotationGestureRecognizer or UIPinchGestureRecognizer it is perfect. But if using UIRotationGestureRecognizer and UIPinchGestureRecognizer only UIPinchGestureRecognizer called, UIRotationGestureRecognizer isn't called.
What is problem in my code?
I think i will make a UISegmented to choose mode , UIRotationGestureRecognizer or UIPinchGestureRecognizer, what should i do?

Thank a lot

Comment: FYI, your NSLog in your pinch recognizer method is after "return" so it's not going to print out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple gestures recognized at once, try using `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`, ex:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: In addition to including the delegate in your .h, make sure to set your `UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegate's to self, ex:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
panRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.drawingView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateRecognizer:)];
rotateRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.drawingView addGestureRecognizer:rotateRecognizer];
```

Comment: I added function to my ViewControler.m and add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to ViewControler.h but problem didn't sloved

Comment: You need to set your gesture's delegate's to "self." Added in the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to recognize the gesture if the other gesture recognizer did not executes.

```
[rotateRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: pinchRecognizer];
```